# Error in Relationship of tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Im having a error when i try to get some data between 2 tables using eloquent.
The error that is giving me is:

```
Error:
Trying to get property of non-object (View:
```

This is my app information

```
DB:
survey:
- id;
- template_id;
- title;


templates:
- id;
- name;
- internal_name;

SurveyModel:
 public function theme(){

        return $this->hasOne(Template::class, 'template_id','id');
}


View:

@foreach($surveys->reverse() as $survey)

        <tr>
        <td>{{$survey->template_id->theme}}</td>

</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the them directly :

```
<td>{{$survey->theme}}</td>
```

And that will return the related `Template` model, instead you could get the attribute you want, example :

```
<td>{{$survey->theme->name}}</td>
```

Hope this helps.